# Fill new added column in existing dynamodb table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Is there any way to backfill newly added column in existing dynamoDB table?

There is data in S3 which has to compared with db and corresponding value should be added to db.

#### DynamoDB table schema:

```
a | b  | x | y | z | new
```

#### S3:

```
x | y | z | d
```

x,y should be compared, and d should be added to new if they match.
a and b are not primary key.

Comment: Are a and b the primary and secondary keys?

Comment: @fendall No they are not